# Execute maven pom script manually

Tags: xml, maven, copy, execute

I have an application, which needs some jars from the local maven repository.
How should I write and how would I execute a (*pom.*)xml file that would copy the jars from the repository to my application folder? Is that possible with maven?

**UPDATE:**

The reason I would require to copy the jars, is due to an old design of the application I'm integrating into maven, so the immediate solution I require is to copy the jars into the application installation folder, so the classes would be imported to the application dynamically, which is how the application is designed.

That been said, should there be any changes to the pom.xml? or just standard pom, plus the maven-dependency-plugin? How would I execute the dependency copy using the pom which will be in the application folder, using CLI?

**UPDATE:**

I've managed to do as I wanted, now the thing is I'm getting greedy, I would also like to copy the sources with the project jar... how can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance,

Adam Zehavi.

Comment: You mean you have dependencies to jars? If yes why would you like to copy them to folder in your application ? nevertheless it's possible to do so (maven-dependency-plugin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide a standard maven `pom.xml` file and declare your needed dependencies in it. You will find enough information on the maven homepage for this.

After that you can use [Maven Dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to copy the decpendencies from the repository. Just type (without any further pom.xml configuration)

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

and the project dependencies will be copied to the folder

`target\dependency`

Comment: What you are suggesting is to perform the first example on this page: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html... how would I define the taregt folder via command line?

Comment: No my suggestion works WITHOUT any special plugin configuration in the pom.xml (just convention over configuration). Your example configures the alternative location in the pom. I suppose you can set the [outputDirectory](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#outputDirectory) via system property '-DoutputDirectory=somewhereElse'